# Using Active Record to update a `jsonb` value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, jsonb

I recognize this is something that i'm trying to do that may not actually be possible to do using ActiveRecord.  However it is one thing that I gotta get sorted out.

At a high level, I need my `jsonb` value to be.

```
{ question: ’q5’, normal: 0, hybrid: 2500 }
```

What I did was create a quick migration setting my new value `condition_price` to a `jsonb` value.  I also have the defaults set to `{}`, as I only have one I need to update.

```
def change
  add_column :condition_columns, :condition_price, :jsonb, default: {}
end
```

Once this was created, I then went out to edit my one specific `condition_price`. What I've officially tried was:

```
ConditionColumns.where(id: 12).first.update!{"condition_price = (question: ’q5’, normal: 0, hybrid: 2500).to_json"}
```

I feel like this is the closest I've gotten to it, but i'm not quite sure where I'm off here.

Would anyone have any ideas on if this is possible or how to do it?

Comment: the update method takes a hash, `update(condition_price: {question: 'q5', etc...}). Also it's shorter to find the model to update with `ConditionColumn.find(12)`. Note, model name should be singular, not plural.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that better solution is use `save` instead of update. LIke:

```rb
condition_column = ConditionColumns.find(12)
condition_column.condition_price['question'] = 'q5'
condition_column.save
```

or

```rb
condition_column.condition_price.merge!('question' => 'q5')
condition_column.save
```

or if you need to use update

```rb
condition_column.update!(condition_price: { question: ’q5’, normal: 0, hybrid: 2500 })
```